# Factors of a stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, stochastic-matrices

If $A B = C$ where matrix $C$ is stochastic (all entries are positive and all rows add to $1$) then is it necessary that both $A$ and $B$ be stochastic?

Comment: Positive or non-negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary.

It may be that $A$ and $B$ **are** both stochastic:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix} \implies C = AB = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix} . $$

It may be that $A$ and $B$ **are not** stochastic:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \implies C = AB = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} . $$

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix}\frac12 & 0\\0 & \frac12\end{pmatrix}.$$